# Choice between groupby and filter with infinite streams in reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

We are using spring webflux in our project. In our project we receive messages over websocket and then we choose a message processing pipleline based on type of the message. As it is with reactor there are multiple operators which can be used to accomplish a task and we are faced with choice of using either [groupby](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_grouping_with_fluxgroupedfluxt) or combination of filter and [ConnectableFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux) to achieve the same. Below is an elaboration of both choices

- ***Filter***

  We use Flux.publish() to broadcast the incoming stream then put multiple subscribers on the [ConnectableFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux). Each subscriber first filters to check if it needs to process the stream further. After adding all the subscribers we call connect on ConnectableFlux. Here is the sample code

```
 public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    ConnectableFlux<WebSocketMessage> connectable = session.receive().publish();
    connectable.filter(msg -> msg.getPayloadAsText().equals("sub1"))
        .subscribe((s) -> System.out.println("Subscriber1"));
    connectable.filter(msg -> msg.getPayloadAsText().equals("sub2"))
        .subscribe((s) -> System.out.println("Subscriber1"));
    connectable.connect();
    return connectable.then();
  }
```

- ***groupby***

  The other choice is to split the incoming stream by applying the [groupby](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_grouping_with_fluxgroupedfluxt)  operator and then filtering and subscribing inside a flatmap. Here is the sample code

```
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    return  session.receive().groupBy(msg -> {
      if (msg.getPayloadAsText().equals("sub1")) {
        return 1;
      } else if (msg.getPayloadAsText().equals("sub2")) {
        return 2;
      }
    }).flatMap(groupedFlux -> {
      if (groupedFlux.key() == 1) {
        groupedFlux.subscribe((s) -> System.out.println("Subscriber1"));
      } else if (groupedFlux.key() == 2) {
        groupedFlux.subscribe((s) -> System.out.println("Subscriber1"));
      }
      return groupedFlux;
    }).then();
  }
```

Our dilemma is the which operator is best suited for our purpose. Which operator will be more performant and more importantly amongst give choices which one is correct usage. Please provide your opinions.

Comment: Did you try the groupBy version? It shouldn't even work.

Comment: Hi, the code is representative of what we do but yes the groupby version does work for us. Can you please shed light on your suspicion on why it wont work?

Comment: @123 `WebSocketSession#receive` returns a `Flux<WebSocketMessage>`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I know it does, what does that have to do with my comment?